# PHP delete an array inside an array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to open a .json file and check if the file contains an array identified by its key. If so, I want to delete it and write the file back to the server. However, I am not having any luck and I think it is my misunderstanding of arrays of arrays in PHP:

**PHP:**

```
$song_id = "j8sUV-ykOB";
$file = "file.json";
$song_list = json_decode(file_get_contents($file),true);

foreach($song_list as $song){
  if(in_array($song_id,$song_list)){
    unset($song);   
    file_put_contents($file,json_encode($song_list,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));          
  } 
}
```

**file.json:**

```
{
    "uKrb3eNCf": [
        "Thunder Rolls",
        "c"
    ],
    "kdOzCKjKN-": [
        "Turn the Page",
        "a"
    ],
    "bDreHgZgxF": [
        "Wild Nights",
        "a"
    ],
    "oeNcwqZJS": [
        "Every day is a winding road",
        "b,j"
    ],
    "j8sUV-ykOB": [
        "Testin",
        "b"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you should first try to do your tasks by yourself in first place.

Comment: What is your error ?..

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski The code provided is the attempt by OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you can avoid a for loop because of the way your data is structured, we can directly call to the specific array of data in your `$song_list` array.

Your song ID are keys so you can go directly and check if the key exists in your song_list array, if it does exist then unset that key.

Here is it in action:

```
<?php
$song_id = "j8sUV-ykOB";
$file = "file.json";
$song_list = json_decode(file_get_contents($file),true);

if (array_key_exists($song_id, $song_list))
{
    unset($song_list[$song_id]);    
    file_put_contents($file,json_encode($song_list,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
}
```

Comment: Should the `file_put_contents()` go inside the `if` statement?

Comment: @TripleC you are quite correct, it should, I will edit to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to `unset` the `$song_list[$key]`, not the `$song` variable:

```
foreach($song_list as $key => $song){
  if(in_array($song_id,$song_list)){
    unset($song_list[$key]);          
  } 
}
file_put_contents($file,json_encode($song_list,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

The `$song` variable in your code contains the value of the current element in your json file, doing `unset` on that value makes no sense.

Comment: it would be helpful to OP to provide an explanation of why unsetting $song doesn't work rather than just providing the right answer

Comment: @Aknosis multiples edits and missed that one :) Thanks for noticing that. Added now.

Comment: Reading more carefully, there isn't any reason for the in_array check inside the loop. This could be done outside the loop, but doesn't actually need to be executed at all (with the iterating code)

Comment: Using a foreach construct in this question is un-needed as we can reference the key directly using the `song_id`. Using a `array_key_exists` check is more efficient to check. Your code here is doing a complete check of the array in the foreach and then inside that it is doing the same thing with the `in_array` function so this check is O(n)^2 in comparison to an `array_key_exists`  check which is O(n) but almost O(1) as it does not iterate through every single object.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$song_id = "j8sUV-ykOB";
$file = "file.json";
$song_list = json_decode(file_get_contents($file),true);
$new_array = array();

foreach($song_list as $key => $song){
    if($key != $song_id){
        $new_array[$key] = $song; 
    }  
}

file_put_contents($file,json_encode($new_array,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
?>
```

This code is successfully work foe me. In foreach check $song_id is equal to Key of array or not. if not insert this array in new array. So after complete all loop of foreach, new array created. So write json file again after decoded this new array. Thanks

Comment: There is no need to go through each index if each array has a unique key which we know and can call directly.